# Compare data in two arraylist and do update in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:

I have two different list of array

**List A**

```
1111,A,B,C  
1111,E,E,F  
1111,Z,Z,Z  
2222,C,D,E  
4444,E,E,E  
.....
```

**List B**

```
1111,123,N  
2222,222,Y  
3333,333,N   
4444,444,N  
.....
```

So basically, List A will have duplicate value in column 1.

What I would like to do is to

1. Search List B using column 1 data from List A.  After it finds a row in List B that matches the data (i.e. 1111), it updates List B, column 3 with a certain value (i.e.N).
2. Later on when I process List B, depending on the value in column 3 for each row, I know I need to go to List A to get the data.

Now I would like to know how I can do it?  Also, when I do #2 above, there are duplicate rows for one value (i.e. 1111), how can I make sure I have got all data?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'll get the inevitable answer out of the way:  this is a textbook example of when to use a relational database.

Comment: List A is actually a query from an Oracle Database.  Since there are many records in the database table and if I don't put the whole table to an array, the program needs to query the database for each value in List B and there can be more than 100,000 rows.

Comment: @Ding, it sounds like list B is not in a database. But if you insert just the relevant data (in your example, column 1, 3 of each row) into a temporary table, you can do all the filtering queries in the database, and pull out what you need... Is this not feasible under your circumstances?

Comment: @Dilum, this is not feasible as we don't want to touch anything in the database.  Now I am able to accomplish #1 above using two for loop and when it finds a match, I set it to "break".

Now my question is on #2, when I process List B, for each row, if I see a Y on column 3, I need to go to List A  and get all 3 rows (i.e. 1111) and use all data from that row.  Other than another for loop, is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: @Ding, List A is in the database, and it can have > 100K rows? What is the typical (and maximum) size of list B?

Comment: @Dilum. List A size is less than List B. Say List B may have more than 100,000 and for each row, it may or may not have a reference in List A. At the same time, it may have more than 1 record in List A. I think I have found a solution for my case. I just put one more column in List A. When one row is processed, I mark it finished so next time when I loop that List, that row will not be chosen. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through A putting the column 1 values into a HashSet.

Next, iterate through B and set the value of column 3 to be whether or not your HashSet contains the value in column 1 (of B).